# Pandas sort on Date in DataFrame not sorting properly

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

The following code segment reads in `sample_data.csv` into a DataFrame and sorts by `observation_time`. The `sort()` routine doesn't properly sort the date/time.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/data/sample_data.csv')
df = df.sort(['observation_time'])
df.to_csv('C:/data/outfile.csv')
```

[using Pandas 0.12 from Anaconda 32-bit windows]

Input `sample_data.csv`:

```
latitude    longitude   vessel_name observation_time
1.031000018 -79.68883514    aqasi           12/28/2012 10:40
1.032833338 -79.71916199    aqasi           12/29/2012 14:06
1.486500025 -80.1906662     aqasi           12/31/2012 4:41
1.466999888 -80.16249847    aqasi           12/31/2012 4:30
2.342833519 -81.46682739    aqasi           12/31/2012 13:40
2.360000134 -81.4936676     aqasi           12/31/2012 13:51
3.816000223 -83.68183899    aqasi           1/1/2013 5:20
3.730499983 -83.55400085    aqasi           1/1/2013 4:24
3.714666843 -83.53016663    aqasi           1/1/2013 4:14
4.986999989 -85.45566559    aqasi           1/1/2013 19:04
6.884333134 -88.21949768    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:11
6.885833263 -88.22200012    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:12
6.886833191 -88.22383881    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:12
6.887333393 -88.22450256    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:13
6.889333248 -88.22800446    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:14
```

Output `outfile.csv`:

```
    latitude    longitude   vessel_name observation_time
9   4.986999989 -85.45566559    aqasi           1/1/2013 19:04
8   3.714666843 -83.53016663    aqasi           1/1/2013 4:14
7   3.730499983 -83.55400085    aqasi           1/1/2013 4:24
6   3.816000223 -83.68183899    aqasi           1/1/2013 5:20
10  6.884333134 -88.21949768    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:11
12  6.886833191 -88.22383881    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:12
11  6.885833263 -88.22200012    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:12
13  6.887333393 -88.22450256    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:13
14  6.889333248 -88.22800446    aqasi           1/2/2013 13:14
0   1.031000018 -79.68883514    aqasi           12/28/2012 10:40
1   1.032833338 -79.71916199    aqasi           12/29/2012 14:06
4   2.342833519 -81.46682739    aqasi           12/31/2012 13:40
5   2.360000134 -81.4936676     aqasi           12/31/2012 13:51
3   1.466999888 -80.16249847    aqasi           12/31/2012 4:30
2   1.486500025 -80.1906662     aqasi           12/31/2012 4:41
```

Comment: Your observation time is sorted as scring. Convert to datetime.

Comment: adding df['observation_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['observation_time']) solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the 'wrong' sorting is that the `observation_time` column is a `string` type column, so it is in fact correctly sorted as `string`.

Converting it to `datetime` type before sorting will produce the desired result:

```
df['observation_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['observation_time'])
```